# It is possible to fill current object with json values from json?

Tags: java, android, gson

I would like to fill object fields with values from Json in object constructor.

```
public AbstractObject(String jsonSerializedObject) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    // Fill object values from json in *current* object
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Could you maybe create a new object and copy all fields to the old one? Why can't you simply go the usual way and use the new object?

Comment: It's been a while... Can you share if you find any alternative or any method that you settled with @pixel

Comment: @Elnino I didn't. Just created copying constructor

Comment: @pixel Okay. So you have the object in the right format. I thought you are trying to fill JSON data to an existing object(which is not of the same schema).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gson doesn't support "populating existing object" (yet).  See issue 431 here.

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=431&q=existing

Answer (score 2):

You can use an InstanceCreator to supply the object that you want to populate.

```
final Foo existing;
InstanceCreator<Foo> creator = new InstanceCreator<Foo>() {
  public Foo createInstance(Type type) { return existing; }
}

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Foo.class, creator).create();
Foo value = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Foo.class);
// value should be same as existing
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.javacreed.com/gson-typeadapter-example/

Override the constructor with the object you want to fill, and then update the object in the `read(jsonReader: JsonReader)` method.

Example in Kotlin:

```
class TypeAdapterGen : TypeAdapter<Gen> {

    var mGen: Gen

    constructor(gen: Gen) : super(){
        mGen = gen
    }
}
```