# Gson deserialize current object with extended class

Tags: java, polymorphism, gson

I'm new to java (Hum... No... I learned Java at school 10 years ago but never really used it since today).

I have an object class which corresponds to my json and was generated with the website http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ (simplified here) :

```
public class ServerDatasObject {
  private Integer error;
  private Boolean isOffline;
  public Integer getError() {
      return error;
  }
  public Boolean getIsOffline() {
      return isOffline;
  }
}
```

And another class used to access all object data (simplified too) :

```
public class ServerDatasHandler extends ServerDatasObject {
  public ServerDatasHandler(String json) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    // how to populate current object using : gson.fromJson(json, ServerDatasObject.class);
  }
}
```

The question is in the code: how to populate current object?
I searched and found something about [`InstanceCreator`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35935419) :

```
final Foo existing;
InstanceCreator<Foo> creator = new InstanceCreator<Foo>() {
  public Foo createInstance(Type type) { return existing; }
}

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Foo.class, creator).create();
Foo value = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Foo.class);
// value should be same as existing
```

but I don't understand how to use it and if it is what I need.

The final goal is to

```
{
  ServerDatasHandler serverDatasHandler = new ServerDatasHandler (json);
  do something with serverDatasHandler.getError()
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why doesn't simple `gson.fromJson(json, ServerDatasObject.class)` work? It creates a new instance of ServerDatasObject that contains all data from the `json`. Isn't it what you need?

Comment: If your class does not contain any logic inside constructor maybe you can just create a static method like `ServerDatasHandler fromJsonConfig(String json)` and just use `gson.fromJson` inside that method?

Comment: About `InstanceCreator` - I never used it inside constructor, though it seems to be fine to return `ServerDatasObject.this` from the `InstanceCreator#createInstance` method. Personally I would prefer either static method to create `ServerDatasHandler` from json or a separate factory

Comment: @RomanProshin if I do what you say, this won't work :
ServerDatasHandler srv = new ServerDatasHandler (json); 
do something with srv.getError()

Comment: @soon yes but same answer than RomanProshin 
BTW I'm having a look at factories

Comment: @Scant With static method instead of `ServerDatasHandler srv = new ServerDatasHandler (json)` you will write `ServerDatasHandler srv = ServerDatasHandler.fromJsonConfig(json)`.

Comment: @soon yes that's what I'm trying but I got a cast error :-/

Comment: Show your actual code, it should not throw cast error

Comment: `public static ServerDatasHandler createServerDatasHandler(String json) {
        logger.debug("debug response complete: {}", json);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        ServerDatasObject serverDatasObject = gson.fromJson(json, ServerDatasObject.class);
        return (ServerDatasHandler) serverDatasObject;
    }`

Comment: Why are you creating `ServerDatasObject` and then trying to cast to `ServerDatasHandler`? Use `ServerDatasHandler.class` instead

Comment: @soon To be honest : I don't know. And now it's working perfectly...
I thought that gson won't do the job because no fields of my json appears in the ServerDatasHandler class... But with extends, it's working...
 Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a separate static method which creates your handler from json:

```
public static ServerDatasHandler fromJsonConfig(String json) {
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  ServerDatasHandler handler = gson.fromJson(json, ServerDatasHandler.class);
  return handler;
}
```

Of course you can also move this method to a factory.

I never used `InstanceCreator` inside constructor because parsing JSON is almost never a task for a constructor. Preferably it should be hidden inside framework or your own factories. Though, your example with `InstanceCreator` should also work if you will return `ServerDatasHandler.this` from the `createInstance` method.